# Understanding Rails Model Function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model - Meeting. In the data base schema - a meeting has tasks. (Task has a model also)
When I save a meeting, there is a method that is called automatically in the Meeting model.
It is written like this:

`def task_attributes=(task_attributes)`

How does it being called? I checked. The method is not written anywhere else in the code.

Comment: it is ruby black magic and probably involves some good metaprogramming and it runs under the hood.

Comment: OK So what is the meaning of this magic function?

Answer (score 0):

If a meeting `has_one :task` and you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :task`, that means that calls to `fields_for :task` will generate params that follow the format `<association_name>_attributes` which may be the reason why you can't find it anywhere in the code.

Comment: No. A meeting has many tasks, and there is no accept_nested_attributes_for in the code at all...

Comment: in that case then, as Kleber said, it must some metaprogramming.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `has_many` association, `ActiveRecord` is saving the children models, in your case tasks.  This occurs whether you set `:autosave` to true or not if you are generating new tasks.  Ruby generates all the code dynamically behind the scenes, that's why you are not finding it.

#### One-to-many Example

When :autosave is not declared new children are saved when their parent is saved:

```
class Meeting
  has_many :comments # :autosave option is not declared
end

meeting = Meeting.new(title: 'staff')
meeting.tasks.build(name: 'boring stuff')
meeting.save # => saves both meeting and task

meeting = Meeting.create(title: 'staff')
meeting.tasks.build(name: 'boring stuff')
meeting.save # => saves both meeting and task

meeting = Meeting.create(title: 'staff')
meeting.tasks.create(name: 'boring stuff')
meeting.save # => saves both meeting and task
```

When :autosave is true all children are saved, no matter whether they are new records or not:

```
class Meeting
  has_many :tasks , autosave: true
end

meeting = Meeting.create(title: 'staff')
meeting.tasks.create(name: 'boring stuff')
meeting.tasks[0].priority = 1
meeting.save # => saves both meeting and task, with 1 as priority
```